# What's the best practice for associating many-to-many table with another table?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, many-to-many

I'm running into this scenario where I'm not sure exactly what the proper way to solve it is. I have a many-to-many table.

```
ProductsTable <--------> DrugsTable

ProductsTable
    |----- ProductID
    |----- ProductName

DrugsTable
    |----- DrugID
    |----- DrugStrength
    |----- GCNSeqNumber
```

The idea is that a `ProductName` can have many `DrugStrength` or `GCNSequNumber`, and one `GCNSeqNumber` can have many `ProductName`.

So, to create this, I created the Model class as follows:

```
public class ProductsTable
{
   public int ProductID { get;set; }
   public string ProductName { get; set; }
   public ICollection<DrugsTable> Drugs { get; set; }

   public ProductsTable()
   {
        this.Drugs = new HashSet<DrugsTable>();
   }
}



public partial class DrugsTable
{

    public int DrugID { get; set; }            
    public string Strength { get; set; }            
    public string GCNSeqNo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductsTable> Products { get; set; }

}
```

And then I mapped it:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ProductsTable>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Drugs).WithMany(i => i.Products)
                .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("ProductID")
                    .MapRightKey("DrugID")
                    .ToTable("RxTable"));
```

So far so good. .NET creates another table called `RxTable` and stores the IDs from `DrugsTable` and `ProductsTable`. Now the issue is, the `RxTable` doesn't have an `id` field. I need to have another table that contains the basic information on the claims (the date, person, as such). What's the best practice of associating another table with these many-to-many table? If I create the `RxTable` manually, would .NET be able to populate the table automatically? How?

Edit made in response to Luca Ghersi's response:

RxTable Rx = new RxTable();

```
        ProductsTable Product = db.Products.Where(x => x.ProductName == productName).FirstOrDefault();

        DrugsTable Drug = db.Drugs.Where(x => x.GCNSeqnumber == gcnSeqnumber).FirstOrDefault();

        if (Product == null)
        {
            Product = AddProduct(productName);
        }

        if(Drug == null)
        {
            Drug = AddDrug(strength, gcnSeqnumber);
        }

        Rx = (RxTable)db.RxTable.Where(x => x.ProductId == Product.ProductId && x.DrugId == Drug.DrugId).FirstOrDefault();

        if (Rx == null)
        {
            Rx.Drugs = Drug;
            Rx.Products = Product;

            db.RxTable.Add(Rx);

        }

        return Rx;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can simply add a autogenerated ID column to the RxTable (I mean, you can create the table by yourself on db with the ID column) an use this column as you please. EF will be able to "ignore" that column. Obviously, if you are going to put a FK on it, EF will ignore that and will simply crash if you are going to delete a record from that table without removing the linked records first.

What about creating a three key mapping table?

Like:

```
 public class ProductsTable
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RxTable> RxTable { get; set; }
}

public partial class DrugsTable
{

    public int DrugID { get; set; }
    public string Strength { get; set; }
    public string GCNSeqNo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RxTable> RxTable { get; set; }

}

public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RxTable> RxTable { get; set; }
}

public class RxTable
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int DrugID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductsTable ProductsTable { get; set; }
    public virtual DrugsTable DrugsTable { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

It's definitively harder to manage, but it's the best way to have everything under control in the code, instead on relying on out-of-EF-control tricks on SQL Server.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Interesting. I'll give it a try and report. Thank you.

Comment: I'm implementing this, and I think it's fairly understandable. One question I have, though, is how do I check before I insert to the RxTable if Product and Drugs already exist or not? Please see my edit if I can do that or not?

Comment: Yes, looks right! One more suggestion: add a UNIQUE KEY constraint on RxTable on (ProductID, DrugID, PersonID); this way you'll be sure that in no case you will have duplicated records :)